# Django @override_settings does not allow dictionary?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-settings

I am new to Python decorators so perhaps I am missing something simple, here is my situation:

This works for me:

```
def test_something(self):
    settings.SETTING_DICT['key'] = True #no error
    ...
```

But this throws a "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression":

```
@override_settings(SETTING_DICT['key'] = True) #error
def test_something(self):
   ...
```

Just to be clear, normal use of override settings works:

```
@override_settings(SETTING_VAR = True) #no error
def test_something(self):
   ...
```

Is there a way to use the decorator with a settings dictionary, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AamirAdnan it doesn't look like a duplicate - very django specific. Hope you agree.

Comment: @alecxe a decorator is just a function so why this can't be duplicate? Obviously it appears in different context here but core problem is same?

Comment: @AamirAdnan well, this is certainly related, i agree, but not a duplicate - just my opinion.

Comment: @alecxe Looks like a duplicate to me...

Comment: Linking a related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42905759/320399

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should override the whole dict:

```
@override_settings(SETTING_DICT={'key': True})
def test_something(self):
   ...
```

Or, you can use `override_settings` as a context manager:

```
def test_something(self):
     value = settings.SETTING_DICT
     value['key'] = True
     with override_settings(SETTING_DICT=value):
         ...
```

Comment: Overriding the whole dict doesn't leave the other keys intact, though, right?

Comment: No, you are removing the rest of settings of the dict. It's not a correct solution for me

Answer (score 8):

Since Python 3.3, you may use `collections.Chainmap` if you wand to override specific values in the dict (or other mapping) object using decorator and keep code clean from context manager.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap

```py
from collections import ChainMap

@override_settings(SETTING_DICT=ChainMap({'key': 'value'}, settings.SETTING_DICT))
def test_something(self):
   ...
```

The above will not override whole dict, and all other values in `SETTINGS_DICT` will be available.

For Python 2.7 you may use backport, which contains `Chainmap` implementation.
https://pypi.org/project/chainmap/

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to override the whole dict either, so I copied the dictionary in question from the `settings` object and just modified the attribute I was interested in:

```
import copy
from django.conf import settings
                                                                                                                                                     
settings_dict = copy.deepcopy(settings.SETTINGS_DICT)
settings_dict['key1']['key2'] = 'new value'

@override_settings(SETTINGS_DICT=settings_dict)
def test_something(self):
    pass
```

It suits my purposes, but if you wanted to make this more widely usable, you could write a short function with a few arguments which could do something like this dynamically.

Note: I tried using `settings.SETTINGS_DICT.copy()` instead of `copy.deepcopy(settings.SETTINGS_DICT)` but that seemed to globally override the setting for all tests.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for me (works with python 3.6):

```
@override_settings(SETTINGS_DICT={**SETTINGS_DICT, 'yournewkey': yournewvalue})
```

Comment: Don't you get `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` with this?

Comment: No, but there's no import in my code - you may want to check something else in yours?