# How to override a nested Django setting in tests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, settings

I know about Django's `override_settingss` and `modify_settings` decorator, but how do you override more complicated settings?

For example, I have a setting like:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...various keys...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES = {
         'anon': '100/day',
     }

    ...more keys...
}
```

I want to set the rate to 10000/day so that I never hit them when working locally. `modify_settings` only works on lists, and to use `override_settings` I'd have to repeat the entire variable (which is about 50 lines long).

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REST_FRAMEWORK[DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES] = { 'anon': '400/day' }` in your local/test settings

you have to override the entire dictionary if you are using @override_setttings.
[Django @override_settings does not allow dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214636/django-override-settings-does-not-allow-dictionary)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I sorted out a few minutes ago too, but I wish there was a way for the override to be only in the tests, where it matters.

Comment: Are you using separate settings for test? If yes you can put this line in your test settings file..

Comment: No....never considered using separate settings for test until now. Is this a common practice? How do you use different settings for tests?

Comment: if you need to use override_settings, you have completely override the dict. Better try using the seperate test settings

Comment: @mlissner to use separate settings (for test, or any other purpose), create a file settings_test.py at the same level as settings.py, with the top line 'from settings import *', then override whatever is needed. Then run your tests with ./manage.py test --settings=package.for.settings_test