# What's the difference between override_settings and modify_settings in Django?

Tags: python, django

Django's [docs on testing tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) mention both the @override_settings and the @modify_settings decorators for usage in tests, but it is unclear from the docs (at least to me) what is the difference between them.

So, what is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`override_settings` will completely change the object stored in side the setting. That is, the original value will be destroyed. `modify_settings` will modify the existing object in place. This works by taking the `append`, `prepend`, and `remove` parameters. The object you're seeing in the documentation is not the `MIDDLEWARE` object, it's a list of steps to perform on the `MIDDLEWARE` object to modify it. For example, given the following `MIDDLEWARE` defined in `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

If you use:

```
@modify_settings(MIDDLEWARE={
    'append': 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'prepend': 'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'remove': [
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    ],
})
```

It yields the final settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE=[
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'
]
```

The same result with `override_settings` would require the entire resulting object above.

The problem here is obvious. If we change the *original* `MIDDLEWARE` settings in `settings.py`, we will have to update our test. If we use `modify_settings`, we would likely still be good to go.

I agree that the docs aren't clear because it doesn't really make it clear that `'append'` is a special keyword, for example.