# How can I rewrite one value in the settings for the test

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, throttling

How can I rewrite 'user': '5/minute' on 'user': '2/day' in the settings for the test

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
         'user': '5/minute'
    }
}
```

How can i do this with @override_settings or mb with context manage? 
I need to apply this only in one test, I can not rewrite the whole dictionary

```
def test_mytest(self):
    value = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK
    value['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES'] = {'user':'2/day'}

    data1 = {}
    data2 = {}
    data3 = {}

with self.settings(REST_FRAMEWORK=value):
    resp1 = self.client.post(self.url, data1, format='json')
    resp2 = self.client.post(self.url, data1, format='json')
    resp3 = self.client.post(self.url, data1, format='json')

assert resp3.status_code == 429, resp3.data
```

But no have 429 error, although the value has changed

Comment: Did you try `@override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['user']='2/day')`?

Comment: So you can not write

Comment: @override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK = {'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES' : {'user':'2/day'}}) - 
This record is also not correct, because I rewrite the dictionary

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24214672/641249

Comment: If in test i write settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['user'] = '2/day' - it's work, иut I can not overwrite the settings for subsequent tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**: With the `@override_default()` wrapper

You want to apply a wrapper function to the `viewset` that you wish to override with this value:

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @api_view(['PUT'])
    @throttle_classes([UserRateThrottle])
    @override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['user'] = "2/day")
    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

Add the wrapper before any view or viewset you wish to apply this overridden customs value.

You also want this in your `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': '13500/day'
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 2**: Custom throttling class

However, if you want different throttling rates for when you're in a test environment, perhaps try the following in `settings.py`:

```
TEST = True ## <-- Set to False when not in testing!!

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.CustomUserRateThrottle'
    )
}
```

And designate your own custom throttling class:

```
from django.conf import settings

class CustomUserRateThrottle(throttling.UserRateThrottle):
    if settings.TEST:
        THROTTLE_RATES = 'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
            'user': '13500/day',
        }
    else:
        THROTTLE_RATES = 'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
            'user': '2/day',
        } 
    return settings.TEST # <-- Custom throttling classes must always return either True or False, so this makes sense.
```

**Solution 3**: directly in your "testing shell":

Include your custom wrapper as we defined above but this time in your `test_something()` method in `test.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase

class TestCase(TestCase):

    def test_something(self):

       with self.settings(REST_FRAMEWORK = ['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['user'] = '13500/day'):


       # START TESTING HERE WITH TEST SETTINGS
```

Comment: I need this only inside the test and this syntax is incorrect(

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what you mean by the syntax being incorrect, maybe you could have a `TEST = True` flag in settings.py. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: @RomanKovalevsky Hi Roman - I've added a few solutions you could leverage in DRF project - I feel solution 3 is the most elegant. I've also decided to use `13500/day` to keep the base unit the same (rather than 5/minute).

Comment: with self.settings(REST_FRAMEWORK = ['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['user'] = '13500/day') - ',' or ')' expected. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: E       with self.settings(REST_FRAMEWORK = ['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['user']="2/day"):
E                                                              ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I can write this in test settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['user'] = '2/day', end no error, but nit override in decorator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178854/discussion-between-roman-kovalevsky-and-micheal-j-roberts).

Comment: Hi Roman...simply add that line to what ever test you have setup. Can I see your test.py code please?

Comment: thanks for your help, i just used a mock and it solved my problem)

Comment: Ideal - let me know if this helped you find the answer, don’t forget to tick this one off if you’re happy it helped you sufficiently!

Comment: @RomanNozhenko same here

Answer (score 5):

```
    from unittest import mock

    @mock.patch('rest_framework.throttling.SimpleRateThrottle.get_rate')
    def test_api(self, get_rate):
        get_rate.return_value = '1/minute'

        from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
        print(api_settings.DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES)
        print(api_settings.user_settings)


        url = 'api'

        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_200_OK)

        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_429_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case you can follow one of the following ways :

**Suggestion 1 :** If you want to *override settings in few specific test cases* the you can use `@override_settings` decorator. But this make no sense if you want that for all test cases, if that's the case then you can follow suggestion 2.

**Suggestion 2 :**  This is more generic and efficient solution.

You can have several settings file  for various running environment (inside settings python module) something like this:

1. `base.py` (containing all of your basic settings)
2. `local.py` (import * from base here and override/add settings specific to local/dev environment)
3. `test.py` (import * from base here and override/add settings specific to test environment)
4. you can also have a settings specific for production environment in `prod.py` or something.

With this setup can run tests like `python manage.py test --settings=yourproject.settings.test`

Comment: Yep - and then it's just a case of using: `python manage.py test --settings=app.settings.test`

Comment: yes, the decision to specify the desired dictionary in the test settings works, I'm not sure the truth that I will be taken (